# Issue on Registering JavasCript Files

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two very simple files : `email.js` and `script.js`

the **email.js**  is

```
$(function () {
    function txtInput(elem) {
      var inputData = $.trim(elem.val());
      if (inputData == "") {
        alert("Filed Is Empty");
      }
      else{
        return inputData;
      }
    }
});
```

and the **script.js**

```
$(function () {
 var proceed = false;
    $("#btnContactUs").on("click", function (e) {
    if (txtInput($('#name'))){
     proceed = true;
    }else{ proceed = false }
       e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

which I registered them in `index.php` as

```
<script src="js/email.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

**Issues:**

**1 -** First of all the  `$("#btnContactUs").on("click", function (e) {});` is not doing any thing so I removed the

```
$(function () {

});
```

from the `email.js` and it started working! Can you please let me know why the `$(function () {});` is doing this?

**2 -** Now the Code is functioning(after removing the `$(function () ...` from email.js) BUT I am  getting a  warning/error in the console as:

[image]

Can you please let me know why this is happening? and how can I fix it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When functions and variables declared with `var` are declared *within* other functions, they are local to their parent functions.  That's why `txtInput` was not defined until you removed `$(function(){});`.

This should have cleared the "not defined" error, especially since your code is now functioning.  Clear the console, refresh the page, and see if it still shows the error.